# Remove string with characters from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am attempting to build a find and remove type functionality with regex. I was able to get to the point where I could remove strings, but discovered that strings with characters could not be removed. When, using a normal string such as `var word = "is"`, it seems to work fine until it encounters a `.`, and then I get strange unwanted output.

Some other unwanted occurrences also developed when incorporating characters into the strings I wanted to remove, for example (note that `var word = "is."` and not `is` in the code below:

```
var myarray = ["Dr. this is", "this is. iss", "Is this IS"]
var my2array = []
var word = "is."

//var regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'gi');
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'gi');

for (const i of myarray) {
    var x = i.replace(regex, "")
    my2array.push(x)
}
myarray = my2array
console.log(myarray)
```

`["Dr. this is", "this is. ", "this IS"]`

This ^ is wrong in several ways (for some reason `iss` is gone, `is.` remains - which was the main string I was trying to remove, the first `is` in the last index is gone...)

I.E. my desired output in this case would be `["Dr. this is", "this iss", "Is this IS"]`

I also tried using template literal, as can be seen in my commented out code.

The goal is to simply remove whatever might be the value in `var word` from my array. Whether the value be a regular string, a string with characters, or just characters. (And of course within the framework of the breaks I have).

Comment: `.` matches any character in a regex, and it’s also not a word character. You can escape it as `\.` (i.e. `"is\\."`) to make it match a literal period instead, but the word boundary will still be before it, not after.

Comment: Be aware of the XY problem phenomenon. You shouldn't assert a possible solution and necessarily reduce your chances of the best outcome. Take anubhava's answer, for example.

Comment: Not related to the question but you could also use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) rather than a for+push. `myarray = myarray.map(str => str.replace(regex, ''));`

Comment: You need to escape the regex special characters in the string `word`. See: [MDN Regular Expressions - Escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping) and [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446170/3982562)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in regex approach:

1. `.` is special regex character that needs to be escaped in your word
2. Word boundary `\b` will not be matched after `.`

You may use this regex based solution:

```js
var myarray = ["Dr. this is", "this is. iss", "Is this IS"]
var my2array = []

var word = "is."

// using lookahead and lookbehind instead of word boundary   
var regex = new RegExp('\\s*(?<!\\S)' +
          word.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&") + '(?!\\S)\\s*')

for (const i of myarray) {
    var x = i.replace(regex, " ")
    my2array.push(x)
}

myarray = my2array
console.log(myarray)
```

- `.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&")` will escape all non-word characters in given 
  word.
- `(?<!\S)` is negative lookbehind to assert that previous character is not a non-space character
- `(?!\S)` is negative lookbehind to assert that next character is not a non-space character

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. If I change my `var word = "is"`, it gets rid of the `is` in `this.`

Comment: Yes I know and I have posted a regex solution for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I am on the verge of accepting this answer, but I have one more question: this seems to work even if the `\\.` is not escaped in `var word = "is\\."` For example `var word = "is."`. I am planning on having user input for `var word`, so it would save me trouble if I didn't need to alter the `var word` string in order to make it work. Will this present a problem for me later or is the escaping in `var word` redundant?

Comment: Escaping is needed when you get something like `is(` from user which if left unescaped will cause regex engine error

Comment: Check updated answer for runtime escaping of special characters in regex.